# Add a custom prompt/reminder when opening or closing (or both) of an MS Word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, popups

When I close a file I want to see a reminder to update specific file headers. The reminder could be as simple as the one word prompt "Headers?"

This is similar to seeing Word's built-in "...save..." prompt.

Is there a way to do this.

Seeing the prompt upon closing would be ideal. If that's not possible, then what about upon opening?

I'm the only person who needs to see the prompt.

Note: I'm using 2010 on a PC. My current workaround is to start a new document with a template that already has a reminder in the form of a reviewer comment. But the comment gets deleted between editing handoffs. So a reminder that pops up when closing or opening the file would be great.

---

**Update**

I followed the instructions at the techrepublic link posted by Frank Thomas (see his comment below), and it worked great for opening a new or existing document.

But not for closing because, now that I've tested it, I realize that in the closing situation I need choices; i.e.:

1. Person attempts to close or to save the document.
2. Person sees a message box with a reminder to do XYZ.
3. Person can choose to

   - save **and** continue working, or
   - save **and** close, or
   - close without saving.

Comment: looks like theres a macro for that here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-automatically-execute-a-word-macro-when-you-create-open-or-close-a-document/

Comment: @Frank Thomas - the techrepublic link was great for prompts upon opening a document. But not the example given for closing because I now realize that there needs to be an option to keep working. I've edited my original post to clarify.